# How to render math formulas in docusaurus v2 for a separate page (not in "docs" folder)?

Tags: math, formula, render, docusaurus

I can successfully render math formulas in docusaurus v2 in all documents (contained in `docs` folder), but I would like to create **a separate document** (referenced from top site bar) with some definitions throughout the whole text and don't want it to appear in documents sidebar. So I create this document in `src/pages` folder but unfortunately math formulas do not render there and all I see is just the text itself like `Some formula: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$`.

I've created `test.md` in `src/pages/` with sample contents:

```
# Test

Some formula: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$
```

and access it with url `http://localhost:3000/mysite/test`. The page appears, but formulas do not render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting `test.md` into `docs` folder and referencing it with `docs/test` solves the issue. However link to it does  appear in the default sidebar.